Greek mythology movie with Paul Newman and Shirley McLaine?
The book Harriet The Spy mentions a movie which isn't named but has several details provided

It's a "spectacular" about the Greek gods
Paul Newman plays Apollo
Shirley MacLaine plays Athena
It's in color
It's in theaters at the time the book is set, so presumably the 1960s

However, I haven't been able to find any such movie. Is this a real movie, or just made up for the book?

Hm... is it possible that this movie is made up, i.e. it only exists within the book? I've checked both actors' IMDb pages and couldn't see any movie at least loosely matching that genre or timeframe.

It was made up.
Paul Newman and Shirley MacLaine's only collaboration was What a Way to Go!, a 1964 American black comedy.

